# JS changes cannot be committed in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I go to the Sources tab in Chrome developer tools to edit a separate JS file, I can modify it. But when I press Ctrl+S, the background color of the editor turns pink while the changes are not saved. A orange triangle with a "!" in it appears on the left side of the filename, and the "*" following the filename does not disappear. Nothing changes with the webpage. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Interesting... I didn't even know you could edit/save files in Chrome this way.  I always do my debugging over HTTP, which would make this impossible.

Comment: Sorry for not making the question clear enough. I am not debugging my own page. I'm just trying to tweak some JS when I browse the page. I Googled for it and was told that changes will be committed to V8 as soon as I press Ctrl+S. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup workspaces in chrome dev tools.

More information here: http://ysmoradi.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/how-do-i-connect-my-chrome-dev-tools-to-my-projects-folders-and-files/

It's easy, in sources tab, right click and the select "Add to workspaces".

Good luck